# getting values from a textbox after checking if the value exists in my database

Tags: c#

I am using asp.net, where I have two pages. One is order-header and another is m-factor. If values of order-header (customer id, order no) matched with  values from the m-factor page then the related values from the database table **mf-Information** should populate the text box, present on third page naming mf-info.

My question is: how do I make the comparison?

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far? Are you using client side scripting at all or just server side? Post some code! :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you might want to use the session object if you want to compare values across pages. Feel free to describe your question a little more

Comment: i have a page order-Header where order(customer id ,order no etc) can be placed ,and other where m-factor(customer id,commission,fright etc) now on the third page mf-info (commission, fright ,etc)values should be shown in text box only if customer id and order no of both the order-header & mfactor page match ,related information from the mfactor page should the text box of the mf-info page.

Comment: Is it some sort of Wizard you created? Could you explain the flow of the pages?

Comment: i am using tab controller. for all the pages. btw i am working on 3-tier architecture in asp.net using c#